# How to call two functions with the same event?

Tags: javascript

I want to display eight elements of first array in eight divs with class .box, and one element of second array in the center div with id center by clicking any div except the middle one with id center. The problem is the two functions named nextElems & arr are not called simultaneously. If one function is called, another does not work. I am able to call the function arr, but how to call the function nextElems simultaneously on the click of any div. 
Your suggestions are always really great and helpful and I am much obliged.

```
   <div id="container"> </div> 

   var words = [40];

    // Showing 8 elements  each time in different divs

    var count = 0;

    var x = "";

    function nextElems() {

        var newArray = words.slice(count, count + 8);

        for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++)

        {
            x += '<div class=box>' + newArray[i] + '</div>';

            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = x;
        }

        x = "";

        count += 8;

    //  Creating div in middle between fourth and fifth div

        if (count <= 40) {

            var center = document.querySelector('#div-3');

            center.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="center"> </div>')

        }

    }

    nextElems();

    //  Showing elements one at a time in order

    var oppo = ["White", "Easy", "Soft", "Low", "Good"];

    var x = "";

    var count = 0;

    function arr() {

        if (count < oppo.length) {

            x += '<div>' + oppo[count] + '</div>';

            document.getElementById('center').innerHTML = x;

            count++;

        } else {

            count = 0;

            document.getElementById('center').innerHTML = "";

        }

        x = "";

    }

    arr();

    $('.box').click(function() {

        arr();

    });
```

I have tried

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  arr();
  nextElems();
});
```

I have also tried it on the click of a button & with other jQuery 
    methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables inside a function scope.
Because now your code performed in the next order:

```
var count = 0;
var x = "";
nextElems();
var oppo = ["White", "Easy", "Soft", "Low", "Good"];
var x = "";
var count = 0;
..
someday later ...
..
arr(); //here you modify your global variables "x" and "count", so next function will use it with unpredictable values
nextElems();
```

so you need to declare it like

```
function nextElems() {
    var count = 0;
    var x = "";

    ...somecode
}
```

and then you can use

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  arr();
  nextElems();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way I need a little more clarification if you could as I am a slow learner.